# Connect via ssh and run a program after a switch user

Tags: linux, bash, shell, expect

I want to create inside a bash script a funcion that connects via ssh to another server (using rsa keys), do a switch user (inserting the password), start a program and then exit with the exit code of the program started.

Below a test I'm doing:

```
    #! /usr/bin/expect
set timeout 120
spawn ssh user1@10.211.55.24
expect ".*user1"
sleep 3
send   "whoami\r"
send  "/bin/su hdfs\r"
expect "*?assword:"
send  "hdfs\r"
expect "$"
send   "whomai\r"
send "exit\r"
```

It works until the switch user, I can switch to the hdfs user but the following commands are not sent (whomai). The $ prompt is correct. Furthermore I'm not able to get the exit code of the command (in this example echo command).

Comment: you could use `ssh -t` to run a command, and have that command by `su - <user> -c '<command to run as them>'` I did something similar at an internship to start a spark shell as the spark admin from a script on my mac

Comment: Yes I know this command but how I pass the password tu the su command? I need to use expect. Or is there a way to pass  the password to the su command?

Comment: Add flag `-d` to the first line and you will be able to see in the debug output what is happening. Note: expect patterns are globs not regexps, so dont use `.*` but `*`. However a `*` at the front of a pattern serves no purpose. Instead of expecting `user1` you would be better looking for the shell prompt, usually `"$ "`.

Comment: maybe you could run expect to do the su on the remote machine